# Style input type file in Laravel

Tags: css, file, laravel, input

I'm trying to style input type file using Laravel -> `Form::file`:

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  {{ Form::file('images[]',  ["class"=>"required","multiple"=>true]) }}
</div>
```

It should look like that:
[image]

I've searcched in web for some solutions and there are possibilities with js but in some of them it's commented that it's not always working in all browsers.

What should be the right way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve this through "label" tag.

```
<label for="form-file">Upload a file</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="form-file" class="hidden" />
```

Just hide the input with css or move it somewhere -9999px to the left, and style the label element to whatever you desire. When user will click on label it will show the upload popup.

I hope this help.

EDIT:
Here is [example](https://jsfiddle.net/tp9rodqt/).
With "Form::file" you can just add label and add ID parametr to your function.

Comment: Thanks, it's nice solution without even js :)

Comment: I put `.hidden` class -> `.hidden {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}`

Comment: But how to display file when user uploads files?

Comment: Sorry but for this you have to use Javascript. If you want only the name you can hide only a half of the file input. This solution could be a problem because in every browser file input looks differently. The javascript solution for this is the best imho.

Comment: Maybe something like Bootstrap filestyle - http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/  for the javascript part ?

Comment: Whatever suits you. Here is example for html5 in pure javascript http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Thanks for example. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Here's you can attach your file in laravel**

```
<div class="row p-t-20">

                                <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="banner_url" value="{{old('banner_url')}}" /> 
                                {!! $errors->first('banner_url', '
                                <p class="text-warning errorBag">:message</p>') !!}
                                <label for="file-upload" id="file-drag">
                                    <div id="file-cont">
                                        Select a file to upload
                                        <br />OR
                                        <br />Drag a file into this box
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <br /><span id="file-upload-btn" class="btn btn-success">Add a file</span>
                                </label>

                                <progress id="file-progress" value="0">
                                    <span>0</span>%
                                </progress>

                                <output for="file-upload" id="messages"></output>
```

this is the easy and the stylish way to input your file in laravel 
please share anyone who needs this thanks